# Is every differentiable function a solution to some first order differential equation that doesn't involve x specifically?

Tags: calculus

This seems to me to be true, but I didn't manage to prove it myself, so I ask here

For every differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, there is a function $g: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(f(x), f'(x))=0$ for every $x$ and for every differentiable function $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ holds that

being true that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $g(h(x), h'(x))=0$ and $h(0)=f(0)$ implies that $h(x)=f(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

i.e every differentiable function $f$ is a solution to some first order differential equation that has translation symmetry.

Comment: Well, there is true vacuously if you take $g(x,y)=1$, for instance.

Comment: Yes, obviosly, i formulated it badly. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to construct a differentiable function $f(x)$ such that $f(0) = f(1)$ and $f'(0) = f'(1)$ but $f(1) \ne f(2)$.  If $f(x)$ satisfies the differential equation
$g(y(x),y'(x)) = 0$, then so does $h(x)=f(x+1)$, and $h(0) = f(0)$ but $h(1) \ne f(1)$.

EDIT: In response to your comment, here's another example.  Consider a differentiable function $f(x)$ such that $f(0) = f(1) = f(2)$, $f'(0) = f'(1) = f'(2) = 0$, and $f(1/2) \ne f(3/2)$, and let 
$$h(x) = \cases{f(x+1) & if $x \in [0,1)$\cr
                f(x-1) & if $x \in [1,2)$\cr
                f(x) & otherwise\cr}$$

Comment: I see, this was helpful. What would happen if i allow for translations along the x axis as well, i.e is there other non-uniqueness other than if f and h are translations of one another ?

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict yourself to algebraic differential equations, [Hölder's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_theorem) says that the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (or equivalently its reciprocal if you want it to be differentiable everywhere) does not satisfy one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i would though like to know what happens for general differential equation (not necessarily algebraic ones)